# Rails 3 routes with slashes and nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-resources

I'm having trouble adding a slashed slug and nested routes.

If I have these routes:

```
resources :courses do
  resources :registrations
end
```

I have these URLs:

```
/courses/7
/courses/7/registrations
```

If I change to_param in Course.rb, I can get some slugs happening in the routes:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{slug}"
end
```

This then gives me:

```
/courses/7-title-of-course
/courses/7-title-of-course/registrations
```

All good so far.

The problem I'm having is after looking at this [http://www.miguelsanmiguel.com/2011/03/17/slug-that-slash](http://web.archive.org/web/20120712020837/http://www.miguelsanmiguel.com/2011/03/17/slug-that-slash):

How do I get this to work with nested resources:

Course.rb:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}/#{slug}"
end
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :courses, :constraints => { :id => /[0-9]+\/.+/ } do
  resources :registrations
end
```

URL:

```
/courses/7/title-of-course
/courses/7/title-of-course/registrations
```

If I set things up like that the Course route is fine but the registration routes are broken.

Any tips here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding constraints:

```
resources :courses, :constraints => { :id => /.*/ } do
  resources :registrations
end
```